# jQuery tablesorter: How to disable sorting on a column by using a class instead of "inline JSON"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am using the [jQuery tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com). I know how to disable sorting on a column by using the jQuery Metadata plugin:

```
<th class="{sorter: false}">Don't sort me</th>
```

But I would rather do this by setting a class, so I don't have to use an additional plugin. Also I think I would remember the class name easier than remembering this JSON syntax. How can I do the same same thing using this syntax:

```
<th class="not-sortable">Don't sort me</th>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the only way to get this to work is modifying the source code of the plugin.

At `jquery.tablesorter.js`, Line 483:

```
function checkHeaderMetadata(cell) {
   if (($.metadata) && ($(cell).metadata().sorter === false)) {
       return true;
   };
   return false;
}
```

Change this code to:

```
function checkHeaderMetadata(cell) {
   if ((($.metadata) && ($(cell).metadata().sorter === false)) || $(cell).hasClass("not-sortable")) {
       return true;
   };
   return false;
}
```

Now the function `checkHeaderMetadata` is also returning true, if the cell has a class named `not-sortable`.

Answer (score 17):

You shouldn't have to modify the source of the plugin.  Assuming your `th` class for not sorting is called `nosort`:

```
function setupTablesorter() {
    $('table.tablesorter').each(function (i, e) {
        var myHeaders = {}
        $(this).find('th.nosort').each(function (i, e) {
            myHeaders[$(this).index()] = { sorter: false };
        });

        $(this).tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'], headers: myHeaders });
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I agree, inline JSON was weird. If you're using tablesorter v2.3 or later, you can actually use data roles to do the same thing - and not have to use the metadata plugin:

```
<th data-sorter="false">...</th>
```

Much cleaner. Note, however, that it requires jQuery.

For more info & a demo:
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-jquery-data.html

All the best!

- Ben

Answer (score 2):

As of version **2.0.x** you can decide at initialisation, which column to ***not*** sort.

Add a property called `headers` and foreach desired column the property `sorter` with the value `false`. Counting columns starts at `0`.

```
jQuery('#element').tablesorter({
    headers: {
        // first column
        0: {
            sorter: false
        },
        // third column
        2: {
            sorter: false
        }
    }
});
```

Example taken from the [docs](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html).